# Where does Photos.app store its library and files?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I switched from iPhoto to Photos and now one feature that was important to me is missing: "Show referenced files in Finder".

For example, that feature was useful to me for selective sharing. Also for other things, like complete Library backups, I think it is very important to know how Photos.app works and where it stores the files.

Comment: @TheBro21 [Code formatting is not a form of emphasis.](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2199) This is the #1 reason I reject some of your edits.

Comment: @grgarsode Ok thanks for advice. I will edit better now

Answer (score 6):

After looking for it, I found it. Quite obvious actually, it is next to the former iPhoto Library.

`~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary`

Researching a little more, because both libraries report the same size, the import from iPhoto to Photos changed all original files to hardlinks.
So either library contains a pointer to one file on disk, thus saving disk space.

For a full backup, I think it is sufficient to backup `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary`.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the following path `/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary`, then right click on `Photos Library.photoslibrary` and select *ShowPackageContents*.

Then you can select the masters folder and backup the original photos.
Hope this helps.